# Make an event end between 2 hours and excluding week-end

Tags: c++, qt

I'm working on a planning application on QML. I'm trying to write the function which allows to calculate startTime and endTime of an event.  My event must start between at a startDayTime and an endDayTime for example 9 a.m. and 3 p.m. The event should not end on week-end too. The endTime must respect these conditions too.

I'm trying to calculate the start time in order to have both start and end time to respect hour boundaries.

This is my program:

```
QDateTime Planning::enDateCalculProcess(QDateTime &startTime, qint64 &time,qint64 &workTime,qint64 &iraTime,QTime &startDayTime, QTime &endDayTime)
{
    qint64 remainingTimeInStartDate= startTime.time().secsTo(endDayTime);
    if(time <= remainingTimeInStartDate){
        startTime=startTime.addSecs(time);
        return startTime.addSecs(iraTime);
    }
    else{

        qint64 numOfDays= time/workTime;
        qint64 remainingTime= time % workTime;
        qDebug()<<numOfDays<<"//"<<remainingTime;
        startTime=startTime.addDays(numOfDays);
        if(remainingTime > startTime.time().secsTo(endDayTime)){
            startTime=startTime.addDays(1);
            startTime.setTime(startDayTime);
            startTime=startTime.addSecs(remainingTime);
            if(!isWeekDay(startTime)){
                QDateTime nexStart=startTime.addDays(8 -startTime.date().dayOfWeek());
                nexStart.setTime(startDayTime);
                startTime=nexStart.addSecs(remainingTime);
            }
        }
        else{
            startTime=startTime.addSecs(remainingTime);
            if(!isWeekDay(startTime)){
                QDateTime nexStart=startTime.addDays(8 -startTime.date().dayOfWeek());
                nexStart.setTime(startDayTime);
                startTime=startTime.addSecs(remainingTime);
            }
        }

        startTime=startTime.addSecs(remainingTime);
        QDateTime endDate=startTime.addSecs(iraTime);
        return endDate;

    }
}
```

I have initially calculated the start and endTime and in case it does not match the conditions I call this function. The user select the start time and we calculate the end by adding the irradiation time to it (iraTime). We must propose a start and end to the user to respect the boundaries.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie i tried but can't make the start and end of my events respect the conditions. I want to know how to solve these kind of problems or what did i do wrong?

Comment: Maybe start out by trying to solve the problem on paper first before committing into writing all of this code.  That's why I asked "what is your question?", since you're showing us all of this code you wrote, and I guess we're supposed to make something of it, but what?

Comment: i did so an applied it. May be i've got the wrong approach about this problem. I'll try again and again